# Changing Background color of Form using string via Textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using the following code so as to get the color of Form's background from user using a TextBox, if the color matches the C# colors, then change the Form background color to what user entered, otherwise it shows a message that the color doesn't exist.

The problem is there is no way to read colors from string consisting the name of colors. So I can't use

```
Form1.ActiveForm.BackColor = Color.text
```

What can I do to resolve that?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string text = textBox1.Text;
  string[] colors = Enum.GetNames(typeof(System.Drawing.KnownColor));
  for (int i = 0; i < colors.Length; i++)
  {
    if (colors[i] == text)
    {
      // Form1.ActiveForm.BackColor = Color.
      MessageBox.Show("BackGround Color of Form Has Been Changed");
    }
    else
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Color You Entered Does Not Exist");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use such code: `this.BackColor = (Color)new ColorConverter().ConvertFromString(textbox1.Text);` But better than a `TextBox` is a `ComboBox` containing colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use such code:

```
this.BackColor = (Color)new ColorConverter().ConvertFromString(textbox1.Text);
```

But better than a `TextBox` is a `ComboBox` containing colors. You can fill the `ComboBox` using `KnowsColor` or any other list of color names:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor)).Cast<KnownColor>().ToList();
```

Then when you want to get selected color from `ComboBox`:

```
if(comboBox1.SelectedIndex>=0)
    this.BackColor = Color.FromKnownColor((KnownColor)comboBox1.SelectedValue);
```

Comment: You may want to exclude a color like `Transparent` because the `Form` doesn't support transparent back color.